# Separating Character from Map in RPG library

Tags: perl, design-patterns

I'm working on an RPG library in Perl and want to make each part as interchangeable as possible. I'm currently creating the Map subsystem and will proceed to the Character subsystem. How should I handle interactions between the character and map?

```
$character->move('left'); # Character encapsulates a Map
```

Or something like

```
$runtime->moveCharacter('left'); # Runtime encapsulates both Map and Character
```

It doesn't seem like a Map should be part of a Character but it seems awkward otherwise.

Also how should I separate the graphical elements of a map's tile and a character's appearance from its underlying data? Or is the graphical aspect part of its data in this case?

I know I'm overthinking this and would like to make this system flexible without being entirely overengineered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part:

Depends. One cannot answer this with a certainty without seeing some design documents for games you want people to be able to realise with your library. If you want inspiration, [Roguelike-Utils](https://metacpan.org/release/Roguelike-Utils) has a global World object that the dependent bits are dangling off.

Second part:

Make the tile an object. The graphical aspect is but one attribute. You know you are doing this correctly when you have decoupled it enough to pass tiles and other stuff off to different renderers resulting in a (scalable or bitmap) graphic, [roguelike](http://enwp.org/Roguelike) ANSI terminal output or even a text description like [ADVENT](http://enwp.org/Colossal_Cave_Adventure).

Since an object encapsulates not only dumb data (appearance), but also associates behaviour with it, you can easily extend the tile system with fluid dynamics or temperature interaction.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful! So for the Tile objects I could have an abstract Map::Tile class for which Map::Tile::Graphical::GTK, Map::Tile::Graphical::Qt, etc. are concrete classes and Map::Tile::Text is another concrete class? Then in the Map I ensure each tile type added is the same? (I really need to brush up on design patterns).